# Transferring Mapped Data To Another Worksheet Than Export it as XML

Tags: excel, xml, vba, export

I'm newbie at VBA coding also very new at import/export XML files on excel.

So, i have a file that has mapped xml data on sheet1. I want to copy this data to sheet2 with some algorithm like multiplying 3rd column by a value and add "A-" as prefix to column 2 etc. After this i want to export this data as xml file with exactly same map on worksheet1.

I did this manually map each attribute at developer/source tab than export but why it can not be done with VBA

So, thanks in advance

Comment: your question is in need of a [mcve]

Comment: Actually, i solved at some point and want to share as answer.However, i've had banned from answering :(